# How to send APDU to PCSC reader from web broswer using javascript

Tags: javascript, pcsc

**Problem:** Sending APDUs from webpage to PCSC reader using javascript.

I don't have much reputation to comment on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the) so I am asking new question.

I have tried/searched most of the solutions provided by experts.

The solution provided by cslashm in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the) 
looks good for my requirement. But, I am not able to execute this solution.

Please guide me to make it work or provide some other similar solution.

Currently, I am successfully using Java Applet approach which uses signed java applet along with javascript. Support of java plugin will be discontinued soon from most of the browsers due to security issues. So, I am looking for browser independent and standard way to communicate to PCSC.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Chrome App that will take advantage of the [chrome.usb](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) API.

It's not a *web browser* solution but your web page could communicate with the local Chrome App via Ajax.

The problem is to get a Smartcard Reader driver that will be recognized by the Chrome runtime.

Comment: [chrome.usb][1] is good API but it does not contains the methods for Smart Card I/O operations.
Though it is not the best approach, I'll further explore the possibilities if this could be extended to serve my purpose. Thanks for pointing out this API. :)

Comment: You can use the CCID protocol to perform PC/SC operations via the USB API.

Comment: I've tried. On a regular Windows 7 x64 box, Chrome can't talk to the reader, the claimInterface() method [errors out with an "access denied" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816037/diagnosing-chrome-usb-claiminterface-error). I'll investigate further, but so far, the most promising course of action seems to be an extension coupled with a [native app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Comment: you should use the zadig generic usb driver, with the new WebUSB api instead.