# How to Access Smart Card from a Chrome browser using WebUSB API and PC/SC?

Tags: javascript, smartcard, apdu, pcsc, webusb

I'm trying to write a web application which needs to exchange messages with a local Smart Card. 
Currently I'm trying to use [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) to connect the Chrome with the smart card reader, but I'm struggling to use the PC/SC specification.

In my researches I found this two topics:

[Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to send APDU to PCSC reader from web broswer using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433488/how-to-send-apdu-to-pcsc-reader-from-web-broswer-using-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Although they deal with the same subject, they have no connection examples.

If anyone has any tips or example of connection I would be grateful.

Comment: What do you have so far in terms of code?

Comment: have the same question, it is a topic that not many info can be found.