# How to use PCSC lite in web application for singing data from smart card

Tags: javascript, smartcard, pcsc

new to smart card I have a requirement to sign and verify  the data from usb smart card through web application . I used apllet but now its not supported by chrome browser . can we use PCSC in place of applet . how can we integrate PCSC with web application and use in javascript Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)