# How to access Smart Card device from a Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Currently I'm developing an web based application which needs a functionality of reading and writing data into a smart card. The implementation needs to be done specifically on chrome browser. Smart card writing reading protocol can be written using JCOP with the standard of ISO-7816. but the concern is to connect the smart card in the client side in chrome ? An help would be very appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)

Answer (score 3):

There are two options in Chrome when it comes to smartcard communication:

1. [Native messaging](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html)
   You can take a look at [chrome-token-signing](https://github.com/open-eid/chrome-token-signing) project for a real-world example.
2. Local application with [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) server
   Browser communicates via the WebSocket with the locally installed application/server  that can access connected smartcard.

Comment: It is not the only option.

Comment: @Supersharp that's correct. I have updated my answer.