# How to interact with a User's Smart Card from my Website?

Tags: java, smartcard, client-side-scripting

I have a web server that is hosting my website. I would like to interact with a client's smart card. To communicate with a Java Smart Card, requires java libraries. So i have implemented a java program that scans the respective computer for a card terminal, finds the smart card, and interacts with it accordingly. The java program works properly on my own computer when tested with my own smart card and reader. But id like to interact with a user's smart card from their computer, by using my website.

Now my issue, is that Java Applets are no longer supported and Java Web Start does not seem efficient or user friendly. 
My goal is to have a user navigate to my website, insert their smart card terminal and the smart card into their personal laptop, and be able to execute my java program from the website.

An example: user goes to website, plugs in smart card. website prompts user to enter in their 4 digit pin.. they enter the pin in... pin is passed to my Java program which has to check the 4 digit pin the user entered, based off of a value within the smart card... smart card returns either success or failure to my java program.. and my java program will update user on their website.

Aforementioned, the java program will scan the computer for a reader and smart card. So to me, this is a combination of client side scripting and server side scripting and im unsure of how this would work.

Heres a live example from the people who make the smart card i am using. It can be seen that they can interact with my smart card, directly from their website. (i tried contacting them about their methods and have yet to hear back)

http://demo.acs.com.hk/epurse-loyalty/#

Is java web start my only option?

If there is anyone who can provide some *civil* insight, that would be wonderful.

Comment: It seems to me that the ACS demo uses a java applet (OnlineDemoApplet.jar).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)