# Will Chrome support CCID USB device in the future

Tags: google-chrome, webusb, iccid

I'm trying to implement an application that can communicate with USB smart card reader on Chromebook.
But I got problem when claiming the interface with USBDevice.claimInterface():

```
DOMException: The requested interface implements a protected class.
```

According to other questions been answered such as:
[WebUSB API protected interface class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591991/webusb-api-protected-interface-class-error) and
[USB device interface has been blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289929/usb-device-interface-has-been-blocked)
I know that CCID is blocked and not supported with WebUSB on chrome.
Is there any way out or will chrome support CCID class in the future?

Comment: Did you mange to find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plan to remove this restriction from WebUSB. The recommended interface for hardware security tokens is the [WebAuthn API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API).