# How to use smart cards on web browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I want to get information from the smart card. I want to do it on the browser. I already have a local solution which I used python with pyscard library mostly. How can I get the information out of smartcard on the browser? Browser does not matter I just need a browser-based or maybe the web-based solution

Thanks

Comment: This is complicated, since browsers typically use PKCS#11 interface, which has a quite restricted functionality. For a rough idea see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807038/1435475).

Comment: You might want to explore [FortifyApp](https://fortifyapp.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding local solution works because Pyscard has access to host machine and can perform some low level operations.
While browser has restricted access and can't perform these actions.

[I found some relevant info here](https://tutor.python.narkive.com/yVDsPIzT/web-using-pycrypto-pyscard)

Comment: You thought that this should be a comment (for which you do not have the privilege yet). Please do not misuse answer posts for comments in that situation. HOWEVER, this post I consider to be a partial answer, i.e. some contribution to the answering process while no full answer exists. And that is an appreciated contribution. That is why I tried my best to polish it up into a more obvious partial answer - and it got undeleted. The difference is not easy, but this one is good enough. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

To get information from card readers these are available options

1-ActiveX (not recomended)

- ActiveX component that loads inside internet explorer and contains
  API’s that can be consumed using JavaScript code
- it is only supported in IE browser and Microsoft stops support for internet explorer that
  mean IE will die in a short time

2-Applet (not recomended)

- Develop an applet that communicates with the local device and interact with the applet using javascript
- Require to configure java run time in the browser.

3-Create host application that runs locally to communicate with devices and send a response to the browser over a web socket  (recommended)

- This method is preferred since the web socket is supported by all browser versions and didn’t require any extra configuration
- Also inside the host application you can execute any complex operation without any limitation.
- I have attached a sample for host application  C# sample on this [repository](https://github.com/mhassanshaker/WebSmartCardReader)

Comment: The repository is a dead link :(