# How to read data from Smart Card Reader in Web Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)?

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins, smartcard, smartcard-reader

What is the best way to read data from Smart Card in Web Browser? Are there any good extensions which will help to get data from Card Reader or maybe some built-in web browser API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)