# Connect webpage to a USB smartcard reader

Tags: web, google-chrome-extension, usb, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I need a webpage with access to a connected smartcard reader, what's the best way to achieve this?

WebUSB banned smartcard readers, the only way around it is to mess with the driver but it would break other things I need.

I thought about using a chrome extension but looks like they haven't got access to usb devices either.

Is the only solution a three layer application?

App running on the OS communicating with the usb device sending messages to -> extension -> webpage

I'm also kinda worried that manifest v3 might break something somehow

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420229/webusb-api-and-pc-sc-smart-card-readers - i.e. using the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve using a USB smart card reader?  That might help with providing a good answer.

Comment: I've got a GUI working on desktop, I want re-make it on a browser, the reader is just going to read plain text from cards, nothing encrypted or fancy

Comment: I see.  Maybe you could consider redesigning the whole thing to turn the use of smart cards into the authentication elements for your new web application.

Comment: no, that's not the scope, the cards are NOT used for authentication

Comment: Alright, got it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems a three layer solution is your only option. You simply cannot access native resources while sidestepping browser provided APIs to do so.

Please ensure whatever you end up developing is *secure* (the very reason smart cards are not allowed in the WebUSB API). Ensuring all communications with a locally hosted application are securely encrypted should be your first step.

[This](https://github.com/jbirkholz/webusbAuth) source provides useful insight into proxying unsupported smart card hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the link, cool project but looks like I would need a fake driver to use it which would break other applications. :(


I wonder weather it could be possible to reverse engineer the original driver to actually use it with webusb and also somehow bypassing the browser restrictions to smartcard readers, it does mention in the README using an extension to bypass restrictions but doesn't say how.
Could it be something different than my 3 layers solution?

Comment: @Axeltherabbit I am perhaps misunderstanding what you are referring to by "driver". My understanding is that the "driver" is the kernel driver to enumerate the device and report it to userspace. Is that inaccurate?

Comment: I'm referring to the proprietary windows driver for the smartcard reader, the one that the Github project suggest to replace with "WinUSB driver"

Comment: Alright - my second question: can you currently access this driver from userspace? Do you have access to appropriate libraries/code to interface with the smart card reader from a normal, native application?

Comment: Yes, they provide an sdk

Comment: @Axeltherabbit Perfect, so you effectively need to implement a native application that accesses this SDK and acts as a proxy for the browser. This can be done via a localhost webserver communicating with a browser extension. This should also comply with Manifest V3.