# How to read/write emv cards from PHP or JavaScript or from code in general

Tags: javascript, php, smartcard, emv

I bought sle4442 cards and an ACR39u reader/writer.

I am currently working on a project where every registered user will get their own card and they can interact with the server using the cards.

In other words, I want my website to be able to read and write on cards.

I know about the softwares available but they are paid and read/write is done using from the app.

Is there a library on PHP or any other languages that allows the above?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_

Comment: It's not so easy as you might think. First of all, you need some kind of browser support to be able to connect to hardware. Furthermore, you need some kind of reversal of control, as a smart card is basically a server (so you have server -> browser -> smart-card-server communication). And yes, I've helped in similar situations, but all proprietary.

Comment: Could you help me in any way? the website should be the main focus but the website without the card is useless. I want the card to at least be used as memory.

Comment: SLE44 is a memory card, not an asynchronous smart card with a processor on its own. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807038/1435475) and its answers should provide enough information to get you started.

Comment: Another issue: It is also important, where the card is plugged in the reader, server side or client side?

Comment: Perfect, if sle4442 is a memory card, it's exactly what i want. i don't really need emv chip right. i need to store on it. It's gonna be client side then sent to server where it will do some computations.

Answer (score -1):

Guys is the card programmable? if yes try to do it in reverse programming
like create valuable from the card reader that will communicate with the website API so that it can read and write when ever the card is used. I just thinking I have never tried this before

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).