# Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, smartcard, webusb

I am trying to access a smart card reader on the client with the Web USB API in order to establish a connection with the server and be able to send commands to the smart card, but it fails to execute device.open().
I attached this code to a button click, and I tried to arrest other applications who were claiming the device but with no fortune.
I know this is possible because of other web applications working similar but i am stuck.
I think the problem is that some other windows process is requestiong the device and chrome can't access it because of it.
Here is what i have:

```
async function requestDevice() {
  const vendorId = 0x04E8;
  const productId = 0x5780;
  navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId, productId }] })
    .then(device => {
       return device.open()
        .then(
           console.log(device.name);
         )
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

On the console:
DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied.

Comment: As far as i know they block certain device classes (including smart card readers) see [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/LZXocaeCwDw/m/GLfAffGLAAAJ). You might also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15807038/5128464) interesting.