# Access pkcs#11 usb token from browser for authenticate tokens

Tags: javascript, applet

currently in my  application I am using java applet and javascript (calling applet function from javascript )for read certificate and sign data from pkcs#11 usb token through browser which working fine. but now chrome and Mozilla Firefox  announced they removing the support for NPAPI and java plugins which creates problem to run applet over the browsers.
Please suggest me some other way so that I can achieve same functionality without using java applet and my application start working with chrome and Mozilla  Firefox . I had tried JAVA web start but its  unable to communicate with browser or javascript .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8793057/279982

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website PKSC #11 smart card authentication and SSL client certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792899/website-pksc-11-smart-card-authentication-and-ssl-client-certificates)

Comment: To access USB token from modern browsers, use [Javascript APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) provided by free Signer.Digital browser extension.