# Digital signature using USB token from web

Tags: javascript, browser, cryptography, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I'd like to sign a hash using certificate on USB token.
I've found [hwcrypto](https://hwcrypto.github.io/) javascript library, which should be able to do that, along with [browser extension](https://github.com/hwcrypto/hwcrypto-extension) or installed application. I've istalled all requirements and then created a page calling javascript library.

```
SCS.sign(handleResponse,request);
```

Window opens, but unfortunately, no certificate has been found (even if certificate can be seen in browser settings). What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have (and have access to) the private keys associated with the certificate? Otherwise you can't sign.

Comment: Which browser are you using?, Can u try with Internet Explorer?

Comment: What server side do you use? It's better to do it at server side, like PHP has a lot of functions to deal with that. Besides that, you have a interface called PKCS#11 defined to handle these things. Look at this answer too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792899/website-pksc-11-smart-card-authentication-and-ssl-client-certificates

Comment: Another possibility is JAVA. I know this does not answer the question, but it's just these functions in JS are experimental yet. Look at Java, maybe it can help you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertStore.html

Comment: @MarioZamora it does not matter, if I would be possible to sign it using Internet Explorer, then I'll be using IE.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [web-eid documentation](https://github.com/web-eid/web-eid.js/)

Search for word "filter" - here it says "Default is sign"

Please make sure your USB Token has sign type certificates and there may be internal check on certificate validity - check you have "not expired" and "sign type" certificate.